# Dropdown value to be the subcollection name to fetch data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

functions:

```
const [damta, setDamta] = useState([]);
 const [drpcrs, setDrpcr] =useState("")
  console.log(drpcrs)
  const crsval = (value) =>{
    if(drpcrs == value.fYCS){
      return FYCS
    }else if (drpcrs == value.sYCS){
      return SYCS
    }else if (drpcrs == value.tYCS){
      return TYCS
    }
  }
    
  

  const FYCS = collection (db, "Courses/SubCourses/FYCS");
  const SYCS = collection (db, "Courses/SubCourses/SYCS");
  const TYCS = collection (db, "Courses/SubCourses/TYCS");
    useEffect(() => {
      const unsub = onSnapshot(
        crsval,
        // collection(db, 'Course/SubCourse/' + drpcrs),
        (snapShot) => {
          let list = [];
          snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
          });
          setDamta(list);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  
      return () => {
        unsub();
      };
    },[])
    console.log(damta);
```

dropdown:

```
<select onChange={(e)=> setDrpcr(e.target.value)} className='selectCS'>
                <option value="fYCS">FYCS</option>
                <option value="sYCS">SYCS</option>
                <option value="tYCS">TYCS</option>
              </select>
```

Here I'm fetching data from Firestore what I really want is to fetch the data according to the dropdown which the user selects. In this code I tried to workaround and gave 3 var FYCS, SYCS, TYCS and gave if else but it still doesn't seems to be working. I'm fetching a sub collection here.

Answer (score 0):

The main problems seem to be:

1. You don't have a dependency on the dropdown value in the `useEffect` so that won't care if you change that value. You need to add it so it runs every time it changes.
2. I think probably when this effect runs, you need to not just subscribe, but also get the data before subscribing (I'm not that familiar with Firestore but I think it only fires events for changes, and you won't have the initial data).

Component logic:

```
const [damta, setDamta] = useState([]);
 const [drpcrs, setDrpcr] =useState("fYCS")

 
    useEffect(() => {
     let activeCollectionPath = 'Course/SubCourse/' + drpcrs
     let activeCollection = collection(db, activeCollectionPath)

      const transformDocs= (docs) => {
         return docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })) 
      }

      getDocs(activeCollection).then((docs) => {
          setDamta(transformDocs(docs))
      })
      const unsub = onSnapshot(
        activeCollection,
        (snapShot) => {
          setDamta(transformDocs(snapShot.docs))
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  
      return () => {
        unsub();
      };
    },[drpcrs])
```